# How can I select same column value as different column from mysql table with join?

Tags: mysql, join

I have a table in mysql datbase name as `communication` and its columns and values are:

[image]

and `contact` table and its columns and values are:

[image]

From above tables I have a requirement to select values like following:

`contact_id`  `f_name`  `l_name`  `phone_number`  `email_address` `creation_date`

Actually I am not a database programmer. And you may ask `what have you tried so far?`. I do not have any idea to try this. **Every problem has solution so I asked here instead to change database design and also do not know is this stupid idea or not**.
If anyone have solution it would be great help for me.

***Note***: email_address and phone_number comes from `communication` table with the help of `medium` field. And `communication` table can have only two medium i.e. `MAIL` and `PHONE`. `EMAIL` was wrong record so `EMAIL` is also `MAIL`.

Thanks

Comment: Is it always just PHONE and EMAIL or may there be arbitrary lines, e.g. HOMEPHONE, OFFICEEMAIL?

Comment: It is always PHONE and MAIL.

Comment: of course there are ways to do this, but the right solution would be to think about your table structures, since this is very error-prone. instead of `medium` you should have a field for each possible type

Comment: @Kryptik what would you suggest to me? Do I change database structure or wait for sometime. :)

Comment: i would change it. quick solution would be to add a column for each "medium" you have in your communication table like `phone_number` `email` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to join `communication` twice, depending on `medium`. This should do the job (untested):

```
SELECT con.contact_id, con.f_name, con.l_name, com1.value AS phone_number, com2.value AS email_address, con.creation_date
FROM contact con 
LEFT JOIN communication com1 ON com1.contact_id = con.id AND com1.medium = 'PHONE'
LEFT JOIN communication com2 ON com2.contact_id = con.id AND com2.medium LIKE '%MAIL%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CC.contact_id, f_name, l_name, CASE WHEN medium='PHONE' THEN  value ELSE value END 'communication', creation_date
FROM COntact C
JOIN Communication CC on CC.contact_id = C.id
GROUP BY CC.contact_id
```

... maybe, maybe not?

**OR** You could join Communication twice with medium as the flag:

```
SELECT id, f_name, l_name, M.value 'email_address', P.value 'phone_number' ,creation_date
FROM Contact C
JOIN Communication P on P.contact_id = C.id AND medium = 'PHONE'
JOIN Communication M on M.contact_id = C.id AND medium = 'MAIL'
GROUP BY id
```

?

Comment: No, friends, there is not field phone_number and email_address in any tables. If it was I can write this query.

Comment: edit on its way ... shooting from the hip though, let me know if there is syntax errors

Comment: never worked with `CASE WHEN` but if it works like i expect, you have to do `CASE WHEN medium='mail' THEN value as email_address ...... ` since there is no table column called email_address.

Comment: @Shane_Yo This does not work. You can see errors with your eyes on your query. No need to execute query.

Comment: I see mail is spelled `EMAIL` and `MAIL` are you able to fix this, or this input from the user? that changes things

Answer (score 0):

**You can pivot the table communication  and join it with contact table**

```
select contact_id,  f_name,  l_name,  phone_number, email_address, creation_date
from contact c 
JOIN (SELECT  contact_id,  
 GROUP_CONCAT(if(Medium= 'MAIL' or Medium= 'EMAIL', value, NULL)) AS 'Email_address', 
 GROUP_CONCAT(if(colID = 'PHONE', value, NULL)) AS 'phone_number'
FROM communication 
GROUP BY contact_id) med
On med.contact_id=c.id;
```

Please note `Medium= 'MAIL' or Medium= 'EMAIL'` is pivot as email_address.